# Fulton, Algebraic Curves, $1.33 (a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

> The exercise asks to decompose $V(X^2+Y^2 -1, X^2 - Z^2 - 1) \subset \mathbb A^3(\mathbb C)$ into irreducible components.

I noticed that both polynomials are irreducible, but this didn’t help me really. I tried to find what the ideal $(X^2 +Y^2 -1, X^2 - Z^2 - 1)$ is, but I couldn’t find a reasonable alternative form (generators). Finally, I tried to write the set itself as the union of the four obvious subsets of $\mathbb A^3(\mathbb C)$ corresponding to the zeros of the above polynomials, but I am not sure if these are irreducible or how to decompose them into irreducible components.

This exercise is in the section corresponding to the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Have you looked at the difference of the two equations you wrote?

Comment: @Mohan yes, what am I supposed to see?

Comment: Can you tell me what it is? In particular, is it irreducible?

Comment: $Y^2 + Z^2$. It is reducible. Why is this useful? (I’m already feeling dumb, so please go easy)

Comment: So, the irreducible factors should give you some components?

Comment: @Mohan so if my original set is $X$, then $X = (X \cap V(Y-iZ)) \cup (X \cap V(Y+iZ))$. Now $X \cap V(Y-iZ)) = V(Y-iZ, X^2 - Z^2 -1)$, and $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z] /(Y-iZ,X^2 - Z^2 -1) \cong \mathbb C[X,Z]/(X^2 -Z^2 -1)$, which is a domain since $(X^2 -Z^2 -1)$ is a prime, therefore $X\cap V(Y-iZ)$ is irreducible. Same for the other one. Does this look good?

Comment: @User : it looks good :)